# Fix Bold "L" when printing div

Tags: jquery, html, css, export-to-pdf

This the code I have

```
var myStyle = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/mystyle.css" />';
window.document.write( myStyle  + $('#containerpdf').wrap('<div/>').parent().html() +'</body>');
```

It works good, but when exporting the letter L seems to be bold, is there a fix for this?

Comment: Which letter "L"? All of them? Can you create a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Hi - I'm not sure where the letter 'L' comes into this. The code snippet you've provided doesn't have a letter L anywhere in it. We can't help if you don't show us all the relevant code. Can you edit your question and add in the other parts that matter? Also - tell us what you've tried yourself to solve the problem and why this hasn't helped. Finally - if you can also set up a jsfiddle so we can have a play around with it, that is often helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know it sounds weird, but *bold L/l in PDF* is a well-known issue in some PDF viewers/libs… for years. Really, go ahead and google it: https://www.google.com/search?q=L+bold+in+pdf

There is probably nothing wrong with your code, or the exported file itself,  just how it's displayed.

Basically it's a font hinting problem, and usually appears only on screen - if you print the file on paper, it will probably come out fine. That's because of higher resolution, printers usually have 300-600 DPI, screens are stuck at ~100, except Retina and other hi-dpi displays.

If you're using Acrobat Reader (or whatever it is called these days), you can try turning off "enhance thin lines" option:

[image]

Changing the font might help, too.

Comment: Huh! Never would have guessed that was a known issue. But is the OP displaying a PDF or HTML?

Comment: You're right, that's a bit unclear. I assumed the problem is in the exported PDF (there's *export-to-pdf* tag). And I met many bold pdf `L`s in my life, so it just clicked somehow… If the issue is showing in HTML, i can't help him without more code.

Comment: what font can I use to remove this issue? I tried sans serif and it work good when previwing the pdf before saving it, but after when saving it, the problem appears again

Comment: @Flezcano Fira Sans (free & open, by Mozilla, http://mozilla.github.io/Fira/) works for me. But i'm afraid it depends on the viewer and display settings, too…